# Print duplicate values once in a multimap

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap

I have a multimap that contains `using myMap= std::multimap <std::string, std::string>;`

here is a sample data that's in it.

```
West;Tuulensuu
West;Keskustori
South;Sammonaukio
West;Rautatieasema
West;Tulli
West;Sammonaukio
East;Sammonaukio
```

I'd like to print just the values, but all the values should only be printed once and should be sorted.

I've tried the following.

```
void print_lines(myMap& tramlines)
{
    for (auto it = tramlines.begin(); it != tramlines.end(); ) {
        std::string key = it->second;

        std::cout << it->second << std::endl;

        // Advance to next non-duplicate entry.
        do {
            ++it;
        } while (it != tramlines.end() && key == it->second);
    }
}
```

It still printed the values more than once. So I tried the following.

```
auto uniq = std::unique(tramlines.begin(), tramlines.end());
tramlines.erase(uniq, tramlines.end());

for(auto item : tramlines)
{
    std::cout << item.second << std::endl;
}
```

But that's giving me the following error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   Prog2Test
```

What are my options here? I can't find anything online that points to printing values, I've found plenty for Keys.

Would iterating through the values and adding them to set and printing them out a good idea?

Comment: *"and adding them to set and printing them out a good idea"*. I would say yes.

Comment: Maps don't store multiple values per key. You need a vector for that.

Comment: maps dont but multimaps do

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique` doesn't work because `map` iterates over `pair<const Tkey, Tvalue>`. It wants to shuffle the pairs around, but can't write over the `const` part. It wouldn't have worked anyway because `multimap` values are only in-order for a given key. `unique` only works on completely sorted collection.

Fortunately, it's not hard to move everything to a set.

```
std::set<std::string> unique;
std::transform(tramlines.begin(), tramlines.end(), std::inserter(unique, unique.end()), [](auto& p) { return p.second; });
```